# Make doesn't work when setting up YOLOv4? Also problems with cmake that I'm not sure if are resolved

Tags: makefile, cmake, yolo, darknet

OS: Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.3 Tricia

I am trying to install YOLO v4 following these instructions: https://robocademy.com/2020/05/01/a-gentle-introduction-to-yolo-v4-for-object-detection-in-ubuntu-20-04/ and have gotten to the part where you have to input the following into terminal:

```
mkdir build_release
cd build_release
cmake ..
make
```

First I had problems with cmake not working on the 3rd line (saying I don't have it when I did) which I resolved by opening a new terminal window.

Now, when I enter

```
make
```

I get the error that translates into something like this:

```
make: *** No target specified, no make file found. Stop.
```

I'm also providing you a screenshot of my darknet folder and the terminal error, maybe the fault is that something is missing from the folder and I cannot find it.
[my folder and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hE7j.jpg)

Comment: edit: I solved it. I was missing the libdark.so file for some reason and simply downloaded it from git. Leaving the discussion if someone has the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you resolved the issue, please consider writing an *answer* post to your own question, describing how to fixed the issue. This way, future viewers to your post can easily see the resolution and learn from it.

Comment: Alternatively, if you do not think the question would have any value for others who may find it in the future, then you have the alternative of deleting it.

Comment: Just remember: implicit in that list of steps is that _each one succeeds_ before the next one is invoked.  If you get errors or a command fails, you have to stop there, figure out what went wrong and fix it, then either start over or at the least, restart where you left off.  If you didn't get a makefile then `cmake` failed (as you say, because it couldn't find a library).